# How to click a button until a condition is met

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I'm testing a day picker component using Cypress. And I would like Cypress to click the 'Previous month' button until, for example, the 'March' text exists in the DOM.

I come across this 'recursive pattern' [in this blogpost](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-recurse/). Is that the recommended way for my use case?

Comment: Did you try it? Do you have some reason to think it might not be?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't. I bailed out when I saw how [much code](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse/blob/main/src/index.js) is required to achieve this seemingly common use case. Hence, I asked this question to see if there's a simpler idiomatic solution.

Comment: Hi. I'm not a cypress expert at all but have you tried a simpler approach like: `click` and then `waitUntil( () => expect(cy.get('[example]').should('exists'))`

Comment: You can apply recursion, but if you like simple code then try setting a fixed testing date with `cy.clock()` then you will know how many clicks take you to March.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd try using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to `observer(<yourDayPickerElement>)`, loop through `addedNodes` to find a node that has "March" textContent for example.

I believe in Cypress you can setup & run the observe with `cy.window().then(() => { new MutationObserver... })`, then once the "March" text is found you can call `cy.click` on so on.

A more simpler approach would be using `wait` & `expect(<yourDayPicker>).<toHaveMatchText...>`, but it's less accurate and can sometimes fail if you're unsure how to expect for that "March" text.

Comment: I totally get the part where you might be unsure how to expect the month but why is this sometimes inaccurate? I'm using this approach a lot that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

With no code is hard to answer properly but could be something similar:

```
function recursiveFunction() {
    cy.get("#your-previous-month-selector").click().then(()=>{
        if(cy.get("#your-month-display").innerText!='March')
            recursiveFunction();
        else
            assert(true) // or return something
    })
}
```